# Merge/Synonym [ring-buffer] in to [circular-buffer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

They are both the same thing: Wikipedia even [redirects ring buffer to circular-buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer).

Their tag wiki entries even indicate they are the same:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ring-buffer/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/circular-buffer/info

[ring-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ring-buffer) has 39 questions tagged (although 8 of them are tagged with [circular-buffer] as well)
[circular-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-buffer) has 172 questions tagged, it also is the first tag to be used (back in 2008)